Some strings are translated even though strings.xml only exist in English
In Android / Jetpack Compose some String resources are translated into other languages even though the app only has one language defined. The case I'm looking at is off which I have defined in a library module:
<string name="off">Off</string>
But a phone set to German will show "Aus" or Ukrainian will show "Вимкнено".
I'm suspecting they are picked up from androidx.compose.ui:ui-android:1.5.4 as Android Studio tells me there are "multiple implementations"

Where DR is the R class of my library module: import my.library.module.R as DR
But why is this the case? I have android.nonTransitiveRClass=true set in my gradle.properties. I would have expected only my modules resources to be picked up.
The app looks pretty weird with a couple of random Strings translated.

Does your my.library.module has multiple string resource files for different languages?

No. It only has one res/values/strings.xml file and no other localized values folders.

Maybe the androidx.compose.ui:ui-android library's resource table is still being merged with your app's resource table & since your app doesn't have translations it is taking from the available strings.
If you are already aware of the strings that is being translated you can rename them into a unique resource name
<string name="appname_off">Off</string>

or
You can add the following code to your app's build.gradle file:
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        resourceConfigurations += "en"
    }
}

This will tell the Android build system to only use the English locale for your app, including the third-party library.

Can you try forcing to use only english in the app.




Then, in your app's build.gradle file, add the following code:
android {
...
localeConfig "xml/locale_config"
}

I think no need to rename drawables only with the strings, as the app currently lacks translations.

Updated the answer, Thanks !
